# How to explain Jarasandha's birth

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, jarasandha

For those who believe in the birth account of King Jarasandha found in the Sabha Parva of the Mahabharata, how do you explain his birth? How is it possible for two deformed fetuses, each looking like half of a human fetus, to form one baby when joined together?

Comment: Just the power of the Rakshasi Jara.

Comment: @GokulRenjith Oh I see. Basically different types of beings have different powers, some which are not really known to average humans. Thank you !!!!!!